# orbeon forms - Dynamic Dropdown remove value

Tags: orbeon

I’m using Oberon forms version 2019.2 CE.

In my form I have Dynamic Dropdown (with search) with country select (required field) and Text field with display code of selected country:

[image]

When I select country, in text field appears selected country code:
[image]

Now I can click ‘x’ sign to remove value form drop down:
[image]

Value in field 'code' has not been deleted. When I click Validate button no error is detected. It seems that when I use 'x' sign to remove value from dropdown, I remove only label, not value.

My question is whether it is possible to remove both label and value, when I click 'x' sign?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this with Orbeon Forms CE 2019.2. This is what I am seeing when running [this form](https://gist.github.com/avernet/c32b052edd4f803c2a64c0ba7acc82d6). If this doesn't help, I'd recommend you update your question to include a link to a minimal form that you are using to reproduce this, with steps to reproduce (and then post a comment, for notification).

[image: Clicking on "x" to clear the value of a dynamic dropdown with search]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem occurs when I use ‘Service performs search’ option set to ‘Yes’. Below you can see how it looks like in my form:
 [image]

Source code of the form: [here](https://gist.github.com/mmakos-profidata/109611cfd2fd09c820116fbf37081be7)

Comment: Just checking: if you got a chance to progress on this one, did you get this work?

Comment: Hi, if I set 'Service performs search’ to 'No' it works, but if I set to ‘Yes’, it still not work. I wondering if this is correct behavior or a bug.

Comment: Could you see if you can reproduce the problem by creating a form on `demo.orbeon.com`? If so, could you then post in a comment the link to that form? ‑Alex

Comment: I found that my problem is the same as issue https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4463
I’m using Oberon forms version 2019.2.0 CE.
I tested on https://demo.orbeon.com/ (with uses 2019.2.2 version) and it works well.
So this problem was fixed in 2019.2.2 release.

Comment: Excellent @m.makos, thank you for testing, and so this will be taken care of in 2020.1 CE, which should come out during the summer. ‑Alex